# Tagging Name in image using face detection in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

In Facebook we have an option to tag names in the photo.As same is there any option to tag name in ios image.Please help

Comment: It's possible to detect faces but you'd have to write the tagging part yourself.

Comment: i have done with face detection.I'm just asking whether any option is available or not.